# How can I create a docker image from the current system?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, boot2docker

I want to create a Docker image after I SSH into the VM and download/config the project. Due to the nature of the project I cannot do this in the config file, it must be done by "freezing" the current system into an image.

Is this possible?

Comment: When you said SSH into the VM, did you mean Container?

Comment: @Sabin Correct. I am still learning the terminology for Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can SSH into the Container, make changes and then you can [commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit) the container, which will save your changes to an image. You can now push this image to registry.
Unless you are using a [data container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), all your changes are saved.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this answer. I am using Google's managed VM's, so I will see if this will actually work in their system. (they use docker).